# Windows error while running standalone pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, localhost

I am trying to import pyspark in Anaconda and run sample code. However, whenever I try to run the code in Anaconda, I get following error message.

> ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:53294)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1021, in send_command
>       self.socket.sendall(command.encode("utf-8"))
>   ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_command
>       response = connection.send_command(command)
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1025, in send_command
>       "Error while sending", e, proto.ERROR_ON_SEND)
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 827, in _get_connection
>       connection = self.deque.pop()
>   IndexError: pop from an empty deque
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 963, in start
>       self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
>   ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:53294)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 827, in _get_connection
>       connection = self.deque.pop()
>   IndexError: pop from an empty deque
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 963, in start
>       self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
>   ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:53294)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 827, in _get_connection
>       connection = self.deque.pop()
>   IndexError: pop from an empty deque
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 963, in start
>       self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
>   ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:53294)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 827, in _get_connection
>       connection = self.deque.pop()
>   IndexError: pop from an empty deque
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 963, in start
>       self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
>   ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:53294)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 827, in _get_connection
>       connection = self.deque.pop()
>   IndexError: pop from an empty deque
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 963, in start
>       self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
>   ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   Reloaded modules: py4j.protocol, pyspark.sql.context, py4j.java_gateway, py4j.compat, pyspark.profiler, pyspark.sql.catalog, pyspark.context, pyspark.sql.group, pyspark.sql.conf, pyspark.sql.readwriter, pyspark.resultiterable, pyspark.sql, pyspark.sql.dataframe, pyspark.traceback_utils, pyspark.cloudpickle, pyspark.rddsampler, pyspark.accumulators, pyspark.broadcast, py4j, pyspark.rdd, pyspark.sql.functions, pyspark.java_gateway, pyspark.statcounter, pyspark.conf, pyspark.serializers, pyspark.files, pyspark.join, pyspark.sql.streaming, pyspark.shuffle, pyspark, py4j.version, pyspark.sql.session, pyspark.sql.column, py4j.finalizer, py4j.java_collections, pyspark.status, pyspark.sql.window, pyspark.sql.utils, pyspark.storagelevel, pyspark.heapq3, py4j.signals, pyspark.sql.types
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/hlee/Desktop/pyspark.py', wdir='C:/Users/hlee/Desktop')
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/hlee/Desktop/pyspark.py", line 38, in 
>       sc = SparkContext()
>
> File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in **init**
>       conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
>
> File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 168, in _do_init
>       self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
>
> File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 233, in _initialize_context
>       return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
>
> File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1401, in **call**
>       answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
>
> File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
>       format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
>   : java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
>       at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
>       at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
>       at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Following is my sample code, and I have no problem running Apache in cmd.

```
import os
import sys
spark_path = r"C:\spark"
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = spark_path
sys.path.insert(0, spark_path + "/bin")
sys.path.insert(0, spark_path + "/python/pyspark/")
sys.path.insert(0, spark_path + "/python/lib/pyspark.zip")
sys.path.insert(0, spark_path + "/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip")

from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

import random
NUM_SAMPLES = 100000

def sample(p):
    x, y = random.random(), random.random()
    return 1 if x*x + y*y < 1 else 0

count = sc.parallelize(range(0, NUM_SAMPLES)).map(sample) \
              .reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
print("Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES))
```

I have downloaded winutils.exe and added HADOOP_HOME variable in environment Varaible and added export  SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1, export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1 in spark-env.sh file. However, I am still getting the same error. Can someone help me and point out what am I missing?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: BTW, I ran netstat -ano in cmd, and saw couple of listening ports as well

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just had to re-estart the kernel.

The problem was that I was creating the environment twice: every time I made a mistake I re-ran the code from the beginning.

Comment: how to restart a kernel?